# How to use character '#' in @nest/config ".env.dev"?

Tags: configuration, nestjs, nestjs-config

Is there any way to use '**#**' in .env.dev file?
My MySQL password has '**#**'

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypass#word
DB_NAME=testdb
NODE_ENV=dev
```

this code recognized like 'mypass'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DB_PASSWORD='mypass#word'` or `DB_PASSWORD="mypass#word"`